# SSO and secondary user ID

Tags: java, active-directory, single-sign-on, kerberos

Is there a way to integrate SSO with a secondary userID and not the windows login ID?

Suppose I login to the windows machine using my loginID `abc`. Then open a web browser and try to login a webapp that already incorporates SSO using a secondary ID `xyz`. Is this usecase possible?

Answer (score 0):

From your tags, I see that you are using kerberos.
Kerberos uses kinit (kinit - obtain and cache Kerberos ticket-granting tickets),
In kinit you can (optionally) specify the principle to use:

```
Synopsis
Initial ticket request:

kinit [-A] [-f] [-p] [-c cache_name] [-l lifetime] [-r renewable_time] [[-k [-t keytab_file_name]] [principal] [password]

Renew a ticket:

kinit -R [-c cache_name] [principal]
```